# Autocomplete no muestra resultados

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando recuperar datos de una bbdd MySQL con un plugin que realiza un typeahead/autocomplete sobre una BBDD.
Tengo dentro del index.php el campo para escribir, los css, el script,.. pero no me recupera ningún valor.

A nivel de logs del sistema, sale que se realiza la petición por lo que "algo" hace.

Los valores a recuperar son países por lo que al buscar por "Spain" por ejemplo

```
MariaDB [countries]> SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = "Spain";
+---------+
| country |
+---------+
| Spain   |
+---------+
```

Este es el fichero ***index.php***:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />  
</head>
<body>

<div class="d-flex vh-100">
  <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="auto form-control input-lg rounded-0" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Script jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#country').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"search.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

Fichero ***search.php***:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "countries");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "SELECT country FROM countries WHERE name LIKE '%".$request."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["country"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

A modo de ejemplo, he subido la web:

https://139.162.206.138/bootstrap/autocomplete_v2/

Que puede suceder o que me faltaría? gracias!

Comment: En MariaDB usas SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = "Spain";
Y luego en PHP "WHERE name LIKE"
No está ahí el error?

Comment: oh! no li vi el "name". Gracias!

Comment: @leanec Al parecer eso solucionó el problema, deberías ponerlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MariaDB usas:
`SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = "Spain";`

Y luego en PHP hay un error en el nombre de la columna cuando usas "WHERE name LIKE"